# flutter build error while running the project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I have created on flutter project in window system. it is running with any errors in window. then I have run the same project on ubuntu. I am facing some kind of path not found errors. I have tried all of these things.

1. run the : 'pub clean' command.
2. run the : 'flutter doctor' 0 issue found in this command
3. created a new project and place all the lib folder into the new project in the ubuntu but still
   i am facing these errors in **console log**.

And there is no single error showing in code editor IntelliJ, I also tried it on Android Studio. I am finding the solution for last 2-3 weeks. but no solution found. here is the console part.

**console log**:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:1:8: Error: Error when reading '../../Documents/work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/cupertino.Dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.Dart';
       ^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:2:8: Error: Error when reading '../../Documents/work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/services.Dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:flutter/services.Dart';
       ^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:10:28: Error: Type 'StatelessWidget' not found.
mixin PortraitModeMixin on StatelessWidget {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:12:3: Error: Type 'Widget' not found.
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:12:16: Error: Type 'BuildContext' not found.
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:24:43: Error: Type 'StatefulWidget' not found.
mixin PortraitStatefulModeMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:24:62: Error: Type 'State' not found.
mixin PortraitStatefulModeMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
                                                             ^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:24:62: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
mixin PortraitStatefulModeMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
                                                             ^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:26:3: Error: Type 'Widget' not found.
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:26:16: Error: Type 'BuildContext' not found.
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:12:16: Error: 'BuildContext' isn't a type.
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:14:18: Error: Method not found: 'SizedBox'.
    return const SizedBox();
                 ^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:26:16: Error: 'BuildContext' isn't a type.
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:28:18: Error: Method not found: 'SizedBox'.
    return const SizedBox();
                 ^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:33:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'dispose'.
    super.dispose();
          ^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:41:5: Error: Getter not found: 'DeviceOrientation'.
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:42:5: Error: Getter not found: 'DeviceOrientation'.
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:40:3: Error: Getter not found: 'SystemChrome'.
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:48:5: Error: Getter not found: 'DeviceOrientation'.
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:49:5: Error: Getter not found: 'DeviceOrientation'.
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:50:5: Error: Getter not found: 'DeviceOrientation'.
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:51:5: Error: Getter not found: 'DeviceOrientation'.
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Documents/work/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/advance_image_picker-0.0.5+3/lib/widgets/portrait_mode_mixin.dart:47:3: Error: Getter not found: 'SystemChrome'.
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/pankaj/Documents/work/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/pankaj/Documents/work/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 46s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Issue in that is it takes your windows path which you created

I think it may resolve your issue..

Open the project folder path in your terminal and run this command:

```
flutter clean
```

Once finish,

Run this command

```
flutter pub get
```

If it will not resolve your issue create new project in ubuntu and copy lib folder in your project and replace that lib folder in new project.

Comment: thanks for replying, i have tried this so many times but this will not fixed the error. So i just remove the advance image picker library and change the  image uploading option with other library. currently i came up with this solution.